# jQuery plugin to zoom and fit to pan oversized images?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

On my site all images uploaded by users should be same size. I would like to give posibility for users to zoom their uploaded image (on pre-save step) inside pan with size to which images should fit. Are there some jquery plugins? I have found only one but it's not free (Smooth Zoom Pan plugin).